# D3js - Smooth transition between 2 paths

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am 2 very different path and I'd like to smoothly change one to make it look like the other one. I have tried using the .transition() method applied on the "d" attribute but it gives very poor results.

Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/yya0m0s0/1/

The d3 code I used is the following:

```
   var svg = d3.select("body")
              .append('svg')
              .attr('width', '375px')
              .attr('height', '490px');


    svg.append('path').attr('d', d_t0);
    svg.selectAll('path').transition()
                         .duration(3500).delay(1000)
                         .attr('d', d);
```

What is the best way to create the kind of transformations?

Many thanks

Comment: Not sure what sort of "results" you're looking for, but have you tried adding [easing](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#d3_ease)?

Comment: Basically I'd like the rectangle to smoothly take the other shape using d3js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that your first path only has 10 segments, and your second has 42 segments. The paths are so different that transitioning between them using the built-in path tweening is impossible.

D3 does a good job of tweening two paths that are similar in structure (same number of segments, and the same types of segments). Things start to get messier the more different the structures are.

Consider [**this example**](http://jsbin.com/xijeyu/1/edit?js,output).

The first two path data `d_1` and `d_2` have the same number and type of segments, only the endpoints change. The transition between these is seamless.

The second two path data `d_3` and `d_4` have the same number of segments, but the final segment is a different type (line in `d_3`, quadratic curve in `d_4`). The transition is fine for all the points up to the last point, but then the final segment shows the same sort of jumpiness that you experienced in your example. This is because a quadratic curve requires a control-point, which must materialize out of thin air when the transition begins, causing the jump.

The bad news is that the only way around this problem is to create a custom tween function for your path data attribute. The good news is that this is a common issue and smart people have come up with solid solutions.

[**HERE**](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/3916621) is a good path tween function that Mike Bostock created.

When implemented on your example it gives a fairly smooth result: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fnwyy8y0/)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is very helpful. If I take 2 paths with the same number of segments, is there a way to "assign" each segment of the first oath to its correspounding one in the other path? For example, in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2brqoo5p/ the transition could be much more simple